# How to detect changes on an Angular @Input array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, input

I have a table filtering component that has an input that is an array of objects. When the component initializes, the objects are all showing their property `isFiltered: false`. If I hard code `setTimeout()` to display the array after one second, the array will show that in fact some of the objects in the array show `isFiltered: true`. I've tried using ngOnChanges(), however angular doesn't detect when these values get updated.

Parent component service call is as follows (`this.filters` is what we're concerned about):

```
      this.supportedTypesService
        .getSupportedPolicyTypes()
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.ngOnDestroy$),
          finalize(() => (this.delayGettingPreferencesOnInit = false))
        )
        .subscribe((response: PolicyType[]) => {
          this.filters = response.map((policyType: PolicyType) => {
            return {
              value: policyType,
              text: PolicyType.getApiValue(policyType),
              isChecked: false
            };
          });
        });
```

`this.filters` is passed down to child component in html as
`[filters]=filters`

Child component has:

```
@Input filters: Filter[]

  public ngOnChanges(): void {
    each(this.filters, (f: Filter) => {
      if (f.isChecked) {
        this.isFiltered = true;
        return false; // to break from forEach loop
      }
    });
  }
```

ngOnChanges() doesn't detect the changes that happen in the array. I've also tried ngDoCheck() but that seems to run infinitely, making me concerned about performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided of the parent component, you set isChecked to false for every filter entry. So it seams that the content of this.filter is updated elsewhere, too.

Do you create a new reference of the this.filter when changing its content in the parent component?
E.g. `this.filter = {...this.filter};`

Angular cannot detected changes inside an array. The variable this.filters is kind of a reference pointing to a memory location. When changing array elements the reference (memory location) remains the same, but the content of the memory it points to changes. Therefore, you need to create a new reference to notify the child component about the changes.